# Refire quartz.net trigger after 15 minutes if job fails with exception

Tags: triggers, quartz.net

I have searched for an answer on how to retrigger a job after a ceratin amount of time, if the job throws an exception. I cannot see any simple way of doing this.

if I set my trigger up like this:

```
JobDetail job = new JobDetail("Download catalog", null, typeof(MyJob));
job .Durable = true;
Trigger trigger= TriggerUtils.MakeDailyTrigger(12, 0);
trigger.StartTimeUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
trigger.Name = "trigger name";
scheduler.ScheduleJob(job , trigger);
```

And MyJob look like this:

```
public class MyJob : IJob
{
    public void Execute(JobExecutionContext context)
    {
        var service = new service();


        try
        {
            service.Download();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }

    }
}
```

how do I make the trigger to refire/retrigger after there is gone 15 minutes if the service.Download() call throws some sort of Exception?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the only option you have is to trap the error and tell Quartz.net to refire immediately:

```
public class MyJob : IJob
{
    public void Execute(JobExecutionContext context)
    {
        var service = new service();

        try
        {
            service.Download();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
              JobExecutionException qe = new JobExecutionException(ex);
              qe.RefireImmediately = true;  // this job will refire immediately
              throw qe;  
        }
    }
}
```

You can find some info [here](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/apidoc/1.0/html/topic415.html) and [here](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/apidoc/1.0/html/topic431.html).

**UPDATE**:

I did some tests and it seems that you can schedule a new trigger inside an executing job.
You can try something like this:

```
public class MyJob : IJob
{
    public void Execute(JobExecutionContext context)
    {
        var service = new service();

        try
        {
            service.Download();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            JobExecutionException qe = new JobExecutionException(ex);
            // qe.RefireImmediately = true;  // this job will refire immediately
            // throw qe;  
            OnErrorScheduleJob(context);

        }
    }

    private void OnErrorScheduleJob(JobExecutionContext context)
    {
        var jobOnError = context.Scheduler.GetJobDetail("ONERRORJOB", "ERROR");
        if (jobOnError == null)
        {
        JobDetail job = new JobDetail("ONERRORJOB", "ERROR", typeof(MyJob));
        job.Durable = false;
        job.Volatile = false;
        job.RequestsRecovery = false;

        SimpleTrigger trigger = new SimpleTrigger("ONERRORTRIGGER",
                        "ERROR",
                        DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(15),
                        null,
                        1,
                        TimeSpan.FromMinutes(100));

        context.Scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);     
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah. This I have read, but it is not a good solution, because it could potential mean that it would refire many thousand times (or even refire million of times). But nice to see that you have come to this conclusion.

Comment: Thanks :D I had sort of the same idea, but this is my first time using quartz so I was not sure if you could use the context.

Answer (score 24):

Actually, its not necessary to create a new JobDetail like described by LeftyX. You can just schedule a new trigger that is connected to the JobDetail from the current context.

```cs
public void Execute(JobExecutionContext context) {
    try {
        // code
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        SimpleTriggerImpl retryTrigger = new SimpleTriggerImpl(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());      
        retryTrigger.Description = "RetryTrigger";
        retryTrigger.RepeatCount = 0;
        retryTrigger.JobKey = context.JobDetail.Key;   // connect trigger with current job      
        retryTrigger.StartTimeUtc = DateBuilder.NextGivenSecondDate(DateTime.Now, 30);  // Execute after 30 seconds from now
        context.Scheduler.ScheduleJob(retryTrigger);   // schedule the trigger

        JobExecutionException jex = new JobExecutionException(ex, false);
        throw jex;
    }
}
```

This is less error prone than creating a new JobDetail. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 9):

I think that the right answer is to use JobListener to retry a job as described here: http://thecodesaysitall.blogspot.cz/2012/03/quartz-candy-part-1.html.

You separate retry logic from Job itself in this solution, so it can be reused.

If you implement retry logic in job as suggested in another replies here, it must be implemented again in every job.

Edit: 
According to the  Ramanpreet Singh note better solution can be found [here](https://blog.harveydelaney.com/quartz-job-exception-retrying/): 
https://blog.harveydelaney.com/quartz-job-exception-retrying/

Comment: I agree. The accepted answer is a "belt and braces" solution (which is fine if you just need to get the job done), but adding a "retry listener" might be a better (and more re-usable) long term solution. I don't think the implementation is perfect, but it's  fine place to start... Source on GitHub: https://github.com/malmgren80/Quartz.Candy

Comment: The linked solution was bettered here: https://blog.harveydelaney.com/quartz-job-exception-retrying/

Comment: @DavidKirkland Your solution rocks. Clean and neat

Answer (score 0):

```
// don't forget to use @PersistJobDataAfterExecution without it, the jobExecutionContext will reset the value of count.     

SimpleTriggerImpl retryTrigger = new SimpleTriggerImpl();
    retryTrigger.setName("jobname");
    retryTrigger.setRepeatCount(0);
    retryTrigger.setJobKey(jobExecutionContext.getJobDetail().getKey());
    final Calendar cal = getCalendarInstance();
    cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 1); //retry after one minute
    retryTrigger.setStartTime(cal.getTime());
    try {
        jobExecutionContext.getScheduler().scheduleJob(retryTrigger);   // schedule the trigger
    } catch (SchedulerException ex) {
        logger.error("something went wrong", ex); 
    }
    JobExecutionException e2 = new JobExecutionException("retrying...");
    e2.refireImmediately();
    throw e2;
```