# Repeat scheduled operation on error

Tags: c#, .net, windows, service

I am using windows service and timer to download file and update my database with the file data every night. I need a way to repeat the operation after some delay if the downloading process or the database update throw exception. Is there better way to do it than using "while" with a counter and Thread.Sleep()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really think about using out-of-the-box Windows Task Scheduler or take a look at [Quartz.NET](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/).

I wouldn't waste my time re-inventing a square wheel when you've issues like yours solved since years. Put your effort on the process rather on *how* to trigger it.

Comment: Does Windows Task Scheduler or any other third party component like Quartz.NET provide any means to reschedule a failed task ? Or should the task implement a redo mechanism

Comment: @Dbuggy See this Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10893559/refire-quartz-net-trigger-after-15-minutes-if-job-fails-with-exception