# How to repeat a Job until is completed in Quartz.Net

Tags: c#, quartz.net

I want to repeat a Job in Quartz.Net until it's correctly completed. I tried something like this:

```
using Common.Logging;
using Quartz;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    [DisallowConcurrentExecution]
    public class ExampleJob : IJob
    {
        private readonly ILog _log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(ExampleJob));

        public Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
        {
            ISimpleTrigger trigger = (ISimpleTrigger)context.Trigger;
            try
            {    
                var myTask = new Task(() =>
                {
                    _log.Info("Starts " + context.JobDetail.Key.Name);

                    if (trigger.TimesTriggered < 3)
                    {
                        _log.Info("I'm going to fail " + trigger.TimesTriggered + " " + context.JobDetail.Key.Name);
                        throw new NotImplementedException();
                    }

                    _log.Info("Success! " + trigger.TimesTriggered + " " + context.JobDetail.Key.Name);
                });
                myTask.Start();
                return myTask ;
            }
            catch(Exception exc)
            {
               throw new JobExecutionException(exc) {RefireImmediately = true};
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With this simple trigger:

```
    ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
        .WithIdentity("trigger, "group")
        .StartNow()
        .Build();
```

It should stop when the "Success!" log statment is executed, and repeats when it fails. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10893559/refire-quartz-net-trigger-after-15-minutes-if-job-fails-with-exception) too but it doesn't work with Quartz.Net 3. Any ideas?

Comment: There's no need for extra Task creation from job. If you don't have async code just return Task.CompletedTask at the end.

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem, the try/catch should be inside the task:

```
using Common.Logging;
using Quartz;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    [DisallowConcurrentExecution]
    public class MyJob : IJob
    {
        private readonly ILog _log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MyJob));

        public Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
        {
            var myTask = new Task(() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    _log.Info("Start!" + context.JobDetail.Key.Name);

                    if (context.RefireCount < 3)
                    {
                        _log.Info("Fails! " + context.RefireCount + " " + context.JobDetail.Key.Name);
                        throw new NotImplementedException();
                    }

                    _log.Info("Ok! " + context.RefireCount + " " + context.JobDetail.Key.Name);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw new JobExecutionException(ex) { RefireImmediately = true };
                }
            });
            myTask.Start();
            return myTask;

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know how to return status of task in main thread? Like if job is complete or not complet let know the main thread about that?