# .NET Core Quartz retry job on exception

Tags: c#, .net-core, service-worker, quartz.net, quartz

I have a .NET 5 worker service with Quartz and I've prepared a job that will execute every day at a specific time. However, there was an occurrence of an exception in the job `Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)` method. And due to the fact that I've just put a `throw;` in the method, the service continued to work normally, but it didn't re-trigger the job.

Program.cs:

```cs
services.AddQuartz(properties, options =>
{
    options.UseMicrosoftDependencyInjectionScopedJobFactory();
});
services.AddQuartzHostedService(q => q.WaitForJobsToComplete = true);
```

DailyJob.cs:

```cs
[DisallowConcurrentExecution]
public class DailyJob: IJob
{
    private readonly ILogger<DailyJob> _logger

    public DailyJob(
        ILogger<DailyJob> logger
        )
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            // DoStuff
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, ex.Message);
            throw;
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Now, my question is if can I somehow avoid this by refiring the job right away? I've seen the type `JobExecutionException` with a parameter `bool refireImmediately`, but if I throw that exception, will it do anything? It's still an exception and I am throwing out of the Execute method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found some helpful info here:
[Refire quartz.net trigger after 15 minutes if job fails with exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10893559/refire-quartz-net-trigger-after-15-minutes-if-job-fails-with-exception)

Should look like this:

```
public Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
{
    try
    {
        // DoStuff
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError(ex, ex.Message);
        
        SimpleTriggerImpl retryTrigger = new SimpleTriggerImpl(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());      
        retryTrigger.Description = "RetryTrigger";
        retryTrigger.RepeatCount = 0;
        retryTrigger.JobKey = context.JobDetail.Key;   // connect trigger with current job      
        retryTrigger.StartTimeUtc = DateBuilder.NextGivenSecondDate(DateTime.Now, 30);  // Execute after 30 seconds from now
        context.Scheduler.ScheduleJob(retryTrigger);   // schedule the trigger

        JobExecutionException jex = new JobExecutionException(ex, false);
        throw jex;
    }

    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```